# NextJS Amplify auth cognito not authenticated on server aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using cognito for authentication of my app.
In local enviroment everthing it's ok whether launch `yarn dev` or `yarn build` and `yarn start`.

In the amplify server deploy the SSR authentication not working: return always "not authenticated".

This is mine package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p ${PORT:=3000}",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@improbable-eng/grpc-web": "^0.14.0",
    "@improbable-eng/grpc-web-node-http-transport": "^0.14.0",
    "@nivo/bar": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/geo": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/pie": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/scatterplot": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/treemap": "^0.74.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.34",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "emotion": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.2.4",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.17.2",
    "human-readable-numbers": "^0.9.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.0",
    "next": "12.0.0",
    "next-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "rc-slider": "10.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-read-more-read-less": "^1.0.7",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.7.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "react-tradingview-widget": "^1.3.2",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3",
    "swr": "^0.5.6",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0"
  }
}
```

This is _app.js (pages/_app.js):

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import "../public/app.scss";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "../src/aws-exports";
import React from "react";
import AuthContext from "../components/context/AuthContext";
import { Header } from "../components/dashboard/Header";
import { Footer } from "../components/dashboard/Footer";
import { SSRProvider } from "react-bootstrap";


Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });

export const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <SSRProvider>
      <AuthContext>
        <Header />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        <Footer />
      </AuthContext>
    </SSRProvider>
  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(App);
```

The test page (pages/test.js):

```
import { withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify";

export default function Test({user}) {
    return <h5>{user}</h5>
}

export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
    const { Auth } = withSSRContext({ req });
    try {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      return {
        props: {
            msg: user.username
        },
      };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return {
            props: {
                msg: err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the error: "The user is not authenticated"
But if I use useEffect in function to retrieve user all is working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow! It's weird. Disabling Restrict access to app resolve the problem (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-control.html).

Anyone that can answer scientifically?